# I have an Excel Macro to split data into different files but need to change the file format and remove columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that does mostly what I want it to do but I have 3 questions. I am changing an .xlsx file to a .csv file UTF8. When the files have been split, the following error pops-up: "The file format and extension of [FILE NAME] don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" Is there something wrong in this code why this error is popping up?

Secondly I have this code running based on entered column number. Now I need to remove the forward and backslashes in that column to make sure the path doesn't get messed up. I found a way to do it through Selection.Replace but I would rather have it happen in the column that is selected through 'sCol' instead of manually selecting Range C:C

Lastly the destination files need to have the columns mentioned in 'sCol' removed and also sCol +1 how would I do this as the code does need sCol first to base the name of the files on, can it be removed afterwards?

- Code Edited Below -

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 13
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".csv"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlCSVUTF8
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "\\pai01file01\EMEA Employee Files\Netherlands\Active EEs\Active EEs\Test"
    Dim el, ws
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    For Each el In Array("/", "\")
        ws.Columns(sCol).Replace What:=el, Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Next el
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim dtToday As Date: dtToday = Date
    Dim DateText As String: DateText = " " & Format(dtToday, "mm yyyy")

    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        ws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & DateText & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not using `dFileFormat` when you save the file - `dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook` should be `dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat`

Comment: I added your suggestions and this is now indeed removing the / and \ from selected columns. Thanks for that! Sadly after that has been done the macro just doesn't do anything anymore. It doesn't do the whole copying and pasting to the new files now. Any idea what broke it?

Comment: Also I would still like to remove sCol and sCol+1 before pasting it to the new file, any ideas for that as well?

Comment: Update: It does seem to work perfectly as intended when running from developer tab and vba but when assigned to a button it does not (this worked before). I have already tried saving the file, re-opening, re-creating the button and also re-assigning the macro but no success

Comment: Can you add your current code as an edit?  What type of button are you using?

Comment: I have added my current code in the main post as an edit

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with the revised code?

Comment: 1. The Macro works perfectly as intended when running from developer tab and vba but when assigned to a button in Excel it does not (this worked before). I have already tried saving the file, re-opening, re-creating the button and also re-assigning the macro but no success. 2. I would still like to remove sCol and sCol+1 before pasting it to the new file, any ideas for that as well?

Comment: Does it run at all from the button? If it does run is there some specific error?

Comment: Are `ws` ("Data") and `sws` (Activesheet) the same worksheet?  It's not clear as written.

Comment: Your comment highlighted to me indeed that these were the same and I updated all 'sws' to 'ws' and now it works al as intended, thanks for that! Any ideas on my last request to remove sCol and sCol+1 before pasting it to the new file?

Comment: `Columns(sCol).Resize(,2).Delete`  ?

Comment: I thought that wouldn't work due to the nature of that sCol being used for the name of the file but noticed this is being added to a dictionary earlier and have now added your line into the 'For each Key' part. It works like a charm now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `dFileFormat` when you save the file -

```
dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

should be

```
dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
```

For the column to be edited - it's not clear if your user is expected to enter a column letter, or the number of the column?
Something like this should work:

```
Dim el, ws
'....
Set ws = Thisworkbook.WorkSheets("Data")
'...
'...
For Each el in Array("/","\")
    ws.Columns(sCol).Replace What:=el, Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2  
Next el
'...
```

Note there's typically no need to Select/Activate objects in Excel before you can work with them.